# How to remove empty line from the end of new class - Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I currently work on Eclipse Juno 4.2 (but problem is connected with older versions of eclipse as well) and I found an irritating issue. When we try to create new class with a default formatter settings, eclipse put an empty line at the end of file.

[image]

I tried to figure out by myself how to remove this annoying line and search in formatter options. I found option that could help solve my problem but i found it's disable by default.

[image]

My question is: How to get rid of this line?

Comment: A lot of unix tools will not process the last line which is why you want the last line to be blank.

Comment: the question is not how to make Eclipse not add the newline, but how to not display it the way it does

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not really an empty line. It just appears that way in Eclipse.

When you see the blank line in Eclipse, it means that the last line of the file is terminated by a new line character. That is, the last characters in your Java file are probably `}\n` (on *nix, with LF line endings) or `}\r\n` (CRLF line endings on Windows), followed in each case by the end of the file.

You can prove this to yourself using `tail` or `cat` on *nix. If the prompt appears on the same line as the last line of code, then there's no trailing new line. If the prompt appears on a separate line, then there is a trailing new line character. If there's a blank line before the prompt, then there's an empty line in the file.

If the above doesn't convince you, use a hex editor. :o) An empty line would appear as two consecutive line endings: `\n\n` or `\r\n\r\n` (on *nix and windows respectively).

There's nothing wrong with the last line of your file having a new line character at the end. In fact, it's a good idea to leave it there, because some tools will warn if it's not there. These tools include [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) (there's an [Eclipse Checkstyle plugin](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/)) and `diff`.

Eclipse allows you to put the cursor there in case you want to add new content to the end of the file. (This isn't often needed in Java, because most people don't put more than one top-level type in a file.)

Best just to leave it there, and get used to Eclipse showing it.

Comment: Hymm I see, but in that case why eclipse give an option showed im my seconed screen "new line at end of file" and what is it for ?

Comment: The option toggles whether the last line has a terminating line-feed character. Perhaps the name is misleading. If it were more precise, it might say "new line *character* at end of file". That isn't the same as "empty line at end of file".

Comment: But I checked files edited with and wihout this option and there is no deference in both. They are exactly the same: ends with '}CRLF' ?

Comment: Here's what I tried: turned the option off; removed the 'line' in Eclipse by hand (the formatter won't remove it if it's there, but it will add it if the option is on); reformatted the file; and checked it didn't add the line ending again. Then examined the file, and observed that there was no end of line character on the last line. Then turned the option on; reformatted; observed the line being added; saved; and examined the file in an external tool, noting that it did have an end of line character.

Comment: nitpick but `diff` doesn't _warn_ about the existence or absence, it merely represents the absence of a newline using a text message, such that the `diff` produced can be used in `apply` to in both cases where a file ends in newline or not