# Empty line at the end of XML files in Eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse

I'm working on android project. I use Eclipse to develop and I use Git source control. In my project there's a requirement that each source file ends with empty line. In eclipse I adjusted java formatter settings and now when I format java code it automatically adds new line at the end of the file. I'd like to have the same setting on XML formatter but I couldn't find one. Is there some way to add new lines in XML automatically using eclipse?

Comment: Have you already tried `Window -> Preferences -> XML -> Xml Files -> Editor`?

Comment: I tried. There's nothing. I'm starting to think I'll need some sort of eclipse plugin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove empty line from the end of new class - Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478373/how-to-remove-empty-line-from-the-end-of-new-class-eclipse)